# How to fix wifi on surface pro 2 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, surface

Basically I have spent the last 6 hours trying to get the wifi to work on my Surface Pro 2 after I just installed the 64bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The Ubuntu install worked fine and is now the only OS on my surface pro 2, I did not dual boot.

I have read every forum and website I could find and tried numerous fixes and nothing has worked. I'm pretty sure I need to install new Wifi drivers however I can't seem to find any information on what drivers I need to download and how to then install them.

I have found that the surface pro 2 uses the Marvell 350N chipset and a lot of things I have read said that this should help me to determine what drivers I need but I am completely lost at this point. I should also point out that I am a complete noob at this type of stuff. I have also seen a lot of people asking for details about the wireless card so here are my results after typing `lspci` in terminal.

```
tom@tom-Surface-Pro-2:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)
tom@tom-Surface-Pro-2:~$
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To get more informations type :lspci | grep -i network

Comment: @GAD3R Your command gives LESS information. Grep filters out some portion of `lspci`.

Comment: @TomD Please add `lsusb`.

Comment: tom@tom-Surface-Pro-2:~$ :lspci | grep -i network
No command ':lspci' found, did you mean:
 Command 'lspci' from package 'pciutils' (main)
:lspci: command not found
tom@tom-Surface-Pro-2:~$ lspci | grep -i network
tom@tom-Surface-Pro-2:~$ :lspci | grep -i network
No command ':lspci' found, did you mean:
 Command 'lspci' from package 'pciutils' (main)
:lspci: command not found'

Comment: tom@tom-Surface-Pro-2:~$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 045e:0795 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 045e:0794 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 03eb:8209 Atmel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:079a Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1286:2044 Marvell Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
tom@tom-Surface-Pro-2:~$

Comment: It's now 4am here in Australia so I've gotta sleep so I can go to work but if you have any ideas I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your device `Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1286:2044 Marvell Semiconductor, Inc.` is driven by the driver *mwifiex_usb*. I am not sure that the driver version included in Ubuntu 14.04 yet covers it. Please load it and check the log for messages.

```
sudo modprobe mwifiex_usb
dmesg | grep mwi
```

Is it missing firmware? If so, please download this file to your desktop: http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.149.3_all.deb Now, back to the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

Comment: Hey @chili555 thanks for the help I tried your suggestions and it returned this tom@tom-Surface-Pro-2:~$ sudo modprobe mwifiex_usb
tom@tom-Surface-Pro-2:~$ dmesg | grep mwi
[    5.352698] mwifiex: rx work enabled, cpus 4
[    5.352832] usbcore: registered new interface driver mwifiex_usb
[    6.512750] mwifiex_usb: mwifiex_usb_disconnect: card or card->adapter is NULL
[   17.345153] mwifiex: rx work enabled, cpus 4
[   27.383655] usb 1-2: mwifiex_cmd_timeout_func: Timeout cmd id = 0xa9, act = 0x0

Comment: tom@tom-Surface-Pro-2:~$ cd ~/Desktop
tom@tom-Surface-Pro-2:~/Desktop$ sudo dpkg -1 linux*.deb
dpkg: error: unknown option -1 
Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
tom@tom-Surface-Pro-2:~/Desktop$

Comment: It isn't `dpkg -1` for the number one. It is, instead `dpkg -i`. It it a lower-case letter I for 'install'.

Comment: thankyou so much @chili555 it's all working now and I couldn't have done it without you!

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it:  http://askubuntu.com/tour  Glad it's working!

Comment: No worries sorry I'm very new to the forum @chili555 The Wifi now connects but I'm having trouble now loading webpages should I ask a new question in a new thread?

Comment: Yes, please. Please include the detail requested here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180 You can paste the data here and give us the link: http://paste.uvubtu.com